# How to make "catkin build" build static libs?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using catkin_tools with melodic and would like to define static libraries system-wide, or at least workspace-wide. I don't want to manually change every CMakeLists.txt in my workspace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326269/how-to-make-%22catkin-build%22-build-static-libs?/) by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1658 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works by adding the CMake-Variable to the catkin config;

```
catkin config -a --cmake-args -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=0
```

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1